# Rolling archival file containing last 1 year's data

Tags: perl, shell, archive

A script needs to be developed to create a archive file containing only last 1 year's data. Script will copy the content of main data file (`CEMI.log`) and append the same to archived log file (`CEMI.Archive.log`). This will happen once in a week (every monday at 3 am). After one year, the script should be able to remove the data from the archive file which is older than a year.

I am stuck at a point where I need to remove last one year's data. How can this be done using shell or perl script?

sample file:

```
-bash-3.2# more test.txt
2015-01-15,09:17:10,101,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,_1.1,L,
2015-01-15,09:18:57,70,al Test,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,1,L,
2015-01-15,10:59:28,1,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:00:52,2,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:00:56,1,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:03:14,1,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:03:38,1,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:04:01,1,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:05:07,2,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,11:06:45,32,,,,Best Practice,9f02745244d6440584b24012d882f935,,L,
2015-01-15,12:57:13,36,,,560909,Best Practice,e8418950-6561-4465-b16b-30e118e826b7,,L,
2015-01-15,13:37:56,1032,,xml-data1,Test,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,Request_1.1,L,Success
2015-01-15,13:39:01,38,,,Internal Test,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,Request_1.1,L,
2015-01-15,13:39:50,113,,xml-dat1,al Test,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,Request_1.1,L,
2015-01-15,13:40:17,74,,, Test,20a6475d-4d0c-4fe4-8765-35065ddfe887,Request_1.1,L,
```

Comment: So you want to delete every file which is older than 1 year?

Comment: There will be only one file. Which will contain 1 year's data. I want to remove the data in that file which is older than 1 year. This file will be updated once in a week with new data

Comment: Than you should provide an example of the file and how the output should look.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample file. This file only contains a day's data. Such file will get appended to the archive file and the resulting archive may contain more than years data.

If you observe the file carefully,each line contains a date at the start of it, I am thinking of using this date to remove the data from the files which more than year old.However, I am not able to build a logic for the same.

Comment: I really think you should reconsider another storage format. Removing the head of a file is cumbersome and offers a variety of possible errors. Why not using rotating log files (files are only appended and age out after the last edit) or not using a database after all?

Comment: Hi, actually this is a requirement of customer, as when needed he can just get a view of single file over a logviwer that we have built for viewing purpose.I think Perl should be able to do this.

Comment: read the file, line by line, ignore lines that are too old, print line that you want to keep - call this prune_log.pl. The write shell script called prune_log.sh:  'prune_log.pl logfile > logfile.tmp; mv logfile.tmp logfile'

Comment: How is the `Success` line supposed to be handled? Shall it be removed if the previous line is too old or shall rotation stop at this point?

Comment: Success is the part of the previous line itself.Hence it should be removed.

Comment: I edited your question another time and moved `Success` to the end of the previous line. Is the text file now displayed as it should be? You can also edit any remaining formatting errors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This will stop at the first line not matching your date format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use File::Copy qw/move/;
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;

# filenames
my $log = "test.txt";
my ( undef, $tmp ) = tempfile( undef, OPEN => 0 ); # get safe temporary filename, but do not open file

# move old log file to temporary location
move $log => $tmp
  or die "Cannot rename '$log' to '$tmp': $!";

# open temporary file (contains old log) and new log
open( my $in, "<", $tmp )
  or die "Cannot open '$tmp': $!";

open( my $out, ">", $log )
  or die "Cannot open '$log': $!";

# calculate a DateTime value one year in the past
my $limit = DateTime->today->subtract( years => 1 );

# skip lines with date that is too old
while (<$in>) {
    if (m/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/) {
        # get DateTime object from matched date parts
        my $dt = DateTime->new(
            year  => $1,
            month => $2,
            day   => $3,
        );

        # keep on skipping lines while dates are too old
        if ( $dt < $limit ) {
            next;
        }
    }

    # if no date was found or date too young, end skipping
    last;
}

# copy all remaining lines from temporary file to new log
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}

close $in  or warn "Error closing '$in': $!";
close $out or warn "Error closing '$out': $!";

unlink $tmp or die "Cannot delete '$tmp': $!";
```

How to execute this:

```
$ cat > test.txt # press Ctrl+D to end text input
2014-01-01,will be removed
stops here
2014-01-01,will be kept because stopped
2015-01-01,would be kept anyway
$ perl rotate_log.pl 
$ cat test.txt 
2014-01-01,will be kept because stopped
2015-01-01,would be kept anyway
```

Comment: Thanks!!.Could you please explain this code for me?

Comment: When I am trying to run this script; getting below error:
`Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl .) at ./rolling_archive.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./rolling_archive.pl line 6`

Comment: Your Perl installation is missing the `DateTime` module. You'll need three modules installed (see `use ...` lines at the top) for my script to run. For an image what Perl modules and the CPAN are and how to install modules see http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/02-perl-community.html#VGhlQ1BBTg

Comment: Can this be achieved without using DateTime module?